# Show Mail Composer When Cell of Table View Is Selected

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am trying to get my table view to present a mailcomposerviewcontroller when a cell is selected.  I have tried using:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;



// Set up recipients
if ([arryData objectAtIndex:0]) {
    [picker setSubject:@"To You"];

    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"emailaddress@here.com"];
    [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];

    // Fill out the email body text
    NSString *emailBody = @"From Me";
    [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}
}
```

Yet, this gets me a crash and

```
which is waiting for a delayed presention of <MFMailComposeViewController:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code snippet seems to be fine here.
Still go through these steps again if you have missed something for that matter.

http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/Mobile-Applications/18176-iPhone-MFMailcomposeviewcontroller-example.html

I hope it helps you!
Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

It is better to **check** first if the device is configured to sent mails. **You can see this** [link](http://ioscoderef.blogspot.com/2012/09/using-inapps-email-for-ios-in-xcode.html)